# Can I submit a JSON to an Oracle Insert like I do with MySQL using Node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, oracle

I have the following code that I used for inserting into MySQL (MariaDB)....

```
import mysql from "mysql";
const INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO CALL_DATE SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MADE_DATE = VALUES(MADE_DATE)";

insertCallDate(callId, server, date){
    const callDate = {
        ...
    };
    return connection.query(
        INSERT_QUERY,
        callDate
    );
}
```

When I move to oracleDB I would like to do something like that again but the closest I can find is something like...

```
const INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO CALL_DATE SET (ID, ...) values (:1, ...)";
```

Is there something similar to MySQL so I can pass a prestructured JSON object to Oracle? Specifically using the Node JS oracledb library?

Comment: could you show the value of  callDate it should be in a format date='2020-03-01',, a= 1, but not a json-

Answer (score 1):

There's a short section on JSON in the [node-oracledb documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#jsondatatype).  To quote an example:

```
const data = { "userId": 1, "userName": "Chris", "location": "Australia" };
const s = JSON.stringify(data);  // change JavaScript value to a JSON string

const result = await connection.execute(
  `INSERT INTO j_purchaseorder (po_document) VALUES (:bv)`,
  [s]  // bind the JSON string
);
```

There are also two runnable examples: [selectjson.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/selectjson.js) and [selectjsonblob.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/selectjsonblob.js).

Most of the JSON technology in Oracle is not specific to node-oracledb, so the Oracle manual [Database JSON Developer’s Guide](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=ADJSN) is a good resource.

You may be interested in SODA, which is also [documented](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sodaoverview) for node-oracledb and has an example, [soda1.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/soda1.js).  It lets you store 'documents' in the DB.  These documents can be anything, but by default JSON documents are used.

Comment: I looked into SODA and it looks interesting but doesn't fit with our data governance controls. Thanks!

Comment: JGleason, could you explain how SODA didn't fit with your data governance controls? We can pass your feedback along to the team.